# Showing $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}\geq \frac{a^{1/3}}{a^{1/3}+b^{1/3}+c^{1/3}}$ for positive $a$, $b$, $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is my problem:

> Let: $a,b,c>0$. Prove that:
> $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+8ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+8ab}}\geq 1$$

In their solution, they wrote:

> Easy to have:
> $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}\geq \frac{a^{1/3}}{a^{1/3}+b^{1/3}+c^{1/3}}$$

How can they have the idea and the inequality below?

Thank you a lot for your explain!

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates to the core ideas of the problem rather than some vague "help me."  "...this step"???  "they have the idea"... "*they*"???  Huh?   *Really*??

Comment: Just denote $x=(b/a)^{1/3}$ and $y=(c/a)^{1/3}$, the inequality is equivalent to $(1+8x^3y^3) \le (1+x+y)^2$. However, I don’t think this final inequality holds true.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](), your problem, and the second part you're referring to, are in multiple AoPS posts, e.g., [A new proof to Vasc's inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h109029p621337), [IMO ShortList 2001, algebra problem 6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17451p821505) and [IMO ShortList 2001, algebra problem 6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17451p9636836). However, all $3$ of them use a power of $\frac{4}{3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}\geq\frac{a^k}{a^k+b^k+c^k}$ be true for any positive variables.

Also, it should be $k\geq1$, otherwise it's wrong for $a\rightarrow0^+$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(a,b,c)\geq0$,

where $$f(a,b,c)=a^k+b^k+c^k-a^{k-1}\sqrt{a^2+8bc}.$$

Now, use $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(1,1,1)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(1,1,1)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}(1,1,1)=0,$$  solve the system and get a value of $k$.

After this prove the inequality for a value of $k$, which you got.

Can you end it now?

P.S. I got $k=\frac{4}{3}$ and the inequality we can prove by AM-GM.

Comment: in my level I didn't learn the 7th line:( Is that $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}$? I have just learnt that but for 1 variable only. Thanks!

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát Yes, of course! $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ it's a derivative by $a$, where other variables are constants.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg FYI, as I explained in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739547/showing-fraca-sqrta28bc-geq-fraca1-3a1-3b1-3c1-3-f#comment10051083_4739547), the AoPS posts [A new proof to Vasc's inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h109029p621337), [IMO ShortList 2001, algebra problem 6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17451p821505) and [IMO ShortList 2001, algebra problem 6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17451p9636836) all use a power of $\frac{4}{3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$, matching your $k=\frac{4}{3}$ result.

Comment: @John Omielan Are you spanferkel?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I assume you're referring to the user spanferkel in the first AoPS post I referred to, i.e., [A new proof to Vasc's inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h109029p621337). I'm not sure why you thought I might be that user, but I'm not. Actually, I don't have any account at all on AoPS.

Comment: @John Omielan Sorry, sorry, sorry. My bad. In any case, thank you for your interest!